# How to sum two XPATH Values

Tags: xpath-1.0

I need to sum the values of the following two XPATHS

1: `/data/dealerLoanApplication[1]/licenseFee[1]`
2: `/data/dealerLoanApplication[1]/titleFees[1]`

When I test the above XPATHs separate I get the correct amounts.

for
`/data/dealerLoanApplication[1]/licenseFee[1]` I get back 50
for `/data/dealerLoanApplication[1]/titleFees[1]` I get back 100.

I am trying to sum(/data/dealerLoanApplication[1]/licenseFee[1]//data/dealerLoanApplication[1]/titleFees[1])
I expect to get back 150.00 but I am getting back 0.00

[image]

Comment: [Don't post pictures of text](/help/how-to-ask), just put in the text, with normal code markdown. Ideally: show your [mcve] code, so show the XML you have (but only the parts that are relevant), and the XSLT that's supposed to do what you need it to do, so that people can properly tell you what you might be doing wrong _and where_.

Comment: You want the sum over a union of two nodes. Members of a union are separated by a pipe, not a slash: `/data/dealerLoanApplication[1]/licenseFee[1] | /data/dealerLoanApplication[1]/titleFees[1]`.